# отфильтровать строку

Tags: javascript

Помогите с алгоритмом, или подскажите как правильно решить задачу.

есть строка:

> 'slug spider rock gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel';

я хочу вернуть отсортированную, условие, всё что не rock, заменить на gravel. a rock оставить как rock:

> 'gravel gravel rock gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel'

```js
var garden1 = 'slug spider rock gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel';

function filtering(value) {
  if (value == 'rock') {
    return 'rock';
  } else {
    return 'gravel'
  }
}


function rakeGarden(garden) {
  var rakedGarden = garden.split(' ');
  rakedGarden.filter(filtering);
}

alert(rakeGarden(garden1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ту (filter) функцию используете. [map()](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#map) обрабатывает каждый элемент массива. И раз нужна строка на выходе, то вернуть (у вас не было возврата значения из функции) ее надо через преобразование массива в строку с помощью [join()](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-join)

```js
var garden1 = 'slug spider rock gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel';

function rakeGarden(garden) {
  var rakedGarden = garden.split(' ');
  return rakedGarden.map(function(value) {
    if (value == 'rock') {
      return 'rock';
    } else {
      return 'gravel'
    }
  }).join(' '); 
}

console.log(rakeGarden(garden1));
```

Comment: А почему filter, работает не так как я ожидал?. Ведь в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) написано: Метод filter() создаёт новый массив со всеми элементами, прошедшими проверку, задаваемую в передаваемой функции.  Правильно я понимаю что filter, возвращает просто, а map ещё умеет преобразовывать элементы, а не просто сверять ?

Comment: @stas0k, он отфильтровывает элементы по условию, а не заменяет значения. Посмотрите там же первый пример.

Comment: разобрался. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Добавил ещё вариант решения:

```js
var garden1 = 'slug spider rock gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel';

const rakeGarden = garden =>
  garden
  .split(' ')
  .map(item => item === 'rock' ? 'rock' : 'gravel')
  .join(' ')

console.log(rakeGarden(garden1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием цикла for:

```js
var garden1 = 'slug spider rock gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel gravel';

function rakeGarden(garden) {

  var tab = garden.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    if (tab[i] != 'rock' && tab[i] != 'gravel') {
      tab[i] = 'gravel';
    }
  }
  var rakedGarden = tab.join(" ");

  return rakedGarden;
}


console.log(rakeGarden(garden1));
```